# c# WMI архитектура ОС на удаленном компьютере

Tags: c#, wpf, wmi

Интересно почему с помощью WMI не удается посмотреть архитектуру ОС на удаленном компьютере, возвращает значение **m["OSArchitecture"]** пустым. На локальном ПК архитектуру ОС получает.

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem");
ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = searcher.Get();

            foreach (ManagementObject m in queryCollection)
            {
                result = m["Caption"].ToString();
                result += "\n" + m["OSArchitecture"].ToString();
            }
```

Пока реализовал получение архитектуры ОС через реестр

```
string OSarch = @"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment";

ManagementClass registryOSarch = new ManagementClass(scope, new ManagementPath("StdRegProv"), null);
ManagementBaseObject inParamsOS = registryOSarch.GetMethodParameters("GetStringValue");
inParamsOS = registryOSarch.GetMethodParameters("GetStringValue");
inParamsOS["hDefKey"] = 0x80000002;//HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
inParamsOS["sSubKeyName"] = OSarch;
inParamsOS["sValueName"] = "PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE";
// Read Registry Value 
ManagementBaseObject outParamsOS = registryOSarch.InvokeMethod("GetStringValue", inParamsOS, null);

            if (outParamsOS.Properties["sValue"].Value != null)
            {
                string OS = outParamsOS.Properties["sValue"].Value.ToString();

                if (OS == "x86")
                {
                    os_info.Content += "\n" + "32-разрядная";
                }

                if (OS == "AMD64")
                {
                    os_info.Content += "\n" + "64-разрядная";
                }
            }
```

Comment: Какая версия Windows на удаленном компьютере?

Comment: Пробовал на нескольких. Windows 10 Pro x64 и Windows 7 Pro x32

Comment: Странно, у меня работает при подключении из Windows Server 2003 к Windows 10, хотя не работает при обратном сценарии. Покажите вывод команды `wmic /node:computer os get /value`, где computer - имя удаленного компьютера. При необходимости авторизации под другим пользователем добавьте `/user:(имя пользователя)`.